# date format in asp.net versus in console application

Tags: .net, datetime, format, culture

I'm deploying a .NET applications to another machine.

in console application, the value of

```
DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();
```

is

```
10 December 2009
```

while in web application the value is

```
23 ذو الحجة 1430 < equivalent in higri calendar
```

How does the web application get the culture from, and why is it different than the console application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer! it was one of the registry records of the users of probably ASPNET or IIS. by using regedit, i found in one of the users international = arabic

Thanks to:
[Change Default Locale in IIS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417497/change-default-locale-in-iis-6-0/1007462#1007462)

Answer (score 4):

In the web.config or machine.config you can specify the default culture for the ASP.Net application through the [globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28VS.71%29.aspx) element.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization 
      culture="en-US"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

It gets it from the machine. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) how you can change it.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely to be the culture of the machine itself - you say you're deploying to a different machine.

Which culture do you *want* it to be in?

EDIT: Your options are:

- Set the culture for the machine itself, affecting the whole of Windows
- *Possibly* set the culture for .NET in general - I'm not sure whether this is available or not in machine.config. It's not something I've ever done.
- Set the culture for each page
- Specify the culture explicitly whenever you parse or format strings

The last one is the least invasive, to be honest. Most methods like `String.Parse` etc have an overload with an `IFormatProvider` parameter. You can specify this as the relevant `CultureInfo`.

Comment: I want the culture to be "en-US" the same as in the console application. From where I can set the culture of the web applications?

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();
```

Comment: I'm afraid i don't want to change the culture from the code. I'd rather understand where the locale was set on the machine itself. Thanks though