# View default locale for IIS 6.0 on Windows 2003 machine

Tags: iis, locale

Is there any method I could use in my web application to view the locale value used by IIS 6.0 on Windows 2003 Server? I call GetLocale which returns me the LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, but I would like to confirm that even IIS is using the same locale.

The reason I want to view IIS locale value is, two web servers having the same LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, display the date in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this post, I've had to use the registry key change a few times...  You want to read roberc's suggestion.  I suggest you backup your registry before you make the change!  If you have 2 machines your trying to sync up, you can also export keys from the two machines/accounts to compare the differences!

[Change Default Locale in IIS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417497/change-default-locale-in-iis-6-0/1007462#1007462)